# Hadoop - How to run another mapreduce job while one is running?

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I already have a high time consuming map reduce job running on my cluster. When I am submitting another job, it is stuck at the below point which suggests that it is waiting for currently running job to complete:

```
hive> select distinct(circle) from vf_final_table_orc_format1;
Query ID = hduser_20181022153503_335ffd89-1528-49be-b091-21213d702a03
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 10
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Starting Job = job_1539782606189_0033, Tracking URL = http://secondary:8088/proxy/application_1539782606189_0033/
Kill Command = /home/hduser/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1539782606189_0033
```

I am running a mapreduce job on `166GB` of data currently. My setup included `7 nodes` out of which `5` are `DN with 32GB RAM` and `8.7TB HDD` while `1 NN` and `1 SN` has `32 GB RAM` and `1.1TB HDD`.

What settings do I need to tweak in order to execute the jobs in parallel? I am currently using `hadoop 2.5.2 version.`

EDIT : Right now my cluster is consuming only 8-10 GB of RAM out of 32 GB per node. The other HIVE queries,MR Jobs are stuck and are waiting for a single job to finish. How do I increase the memory consumption to facilitate more jobs executing in parallel. Here is the current output of `ps` command :

```
[hduser@secondary ~]$ ps -ef | grep -i runjar | grep -v grep
hduser   110398      1  0 Nov11 ?        00:07:15 /opt/jdk1.8.0_77//bin/java -Dproc_jar -Xmx1000m 
-Dhadoop.log.dir=/home/hduser/hadoop/logs -Dyarn.log.dir=/home/hduser/hadoop/logs 
-Dhadoop.log.file=yarn.log -Dyarn.log.file=yarn.log -Dyarn.home.dir= 
-Dyarn.id.str= -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Dyarn.root.logger=INFO,console -Dyarn.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml
-Dhadoop.log.dir=/home/hduser/hadoop/logs -Dyarn.log.dir=/home/hduser/hadoop/logs 
-Dhadoop.log.file=yarn.log -Dyarn.log.file=yarn.log 
-Dyarn.home.dir=/home/hduser/hadoop -Dhadoop.home.dir=/home/hduser/hadoop 
-Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console 
-Dyarn.root.logger=INFO,console 
-classpath /home/hduser/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/home/hduser/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/home/hduser/hadoop/etc/hadoop:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/home/hduser/hadoop/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/home/hduser/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/* 
org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar abc.jar def.mydriver2 /raw_data /mr_output/
```

Answer (score 0):

**STEPS**

Hive runs query plans in stages. 
Some stages depend on other stages and cannot be started until the previous stages have completed.

However, some other stages can run concurrently with others. Having stages run in parallel can save the overall job running time. 
To enable parallel execution of stages, do:

```
set hive.exec.parallel=true;
set hive.exec.parallel.thread.number=8;
```

Parallel execution will increase the cluster utilization.
If the utilization of a cluster is already high, parallel execution will not help much in terms of overall performance.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Even a simple `select * from tablename` is waiting for another job to complete before starting execution. I suppose there is some cluster utilization optimization required as my cluster has 32 GB RAM on all DN and NN and 8.7TB HDD on DNs and 1.1TB HDD on NN.

Comment: Doing a `select * from tablename` without the `where` clause is never a good idea in Big data. It'll try and fetch you all rows and all columns which rightly eats up the space. Try putting in some filter in your query and then execute more than 1 queries in parallel.

Comment: Even if I am using `limit 10` in my query, it is waiting for the other job to complete before starting execution.

Comment: Please use filters in your query, like `where col=5`. Also, did you set the property `set hive.exec.parallel=true;` ?

Comment: I have set this property in `hive-site.xml`. I will test this and get back to you. However, this seems to be a hive property and the issue that I am facing is that after submitting a job via java mapreduce jar over a large dataset, other jobs`(HIVE queries)` are wating for it to finish before starting. I guess I need to tweak some settings in YARN configuration to allow it to consume more RAM to start processes in parallel.

Comment: Edited my question with more info.